# jQuery Animating page 'snap to' looping on scroll end

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

So I have a vertical scrolling site with 'pages' down the way. I want the browser to align the page that's most inview when the user stops scrolling.

I have a method to find which element is inview, and using a simple plugin I have an event that fires when the scroll stops.

The problem I'm having is how to utilise this properly.

I'm animating the browser to scroll to the top of the inview-page at scroll stop. This however starts another scroll and fires everything off again which is causing some weird constant scrolling bugs and leads to it all jumping around the page.

Does anyone have any ideas of a different way of implementing this to avoid the loop? I'm really quite stuck at the moment.

Code below. And thanks for any advice.

```
$(window).bind('scrollstop', function(e){

//this grabs the ID of the div containing my h1 element. This is how I decide which 'page' is inview
var inview = '#' + $('.section-header:in-viewport:first').parent().parent().attr('id');

//then I grab the distance from the top, so that it can be scrolled to
var this_pos = $(inview).offset().top;  

//finally I animate the page to scroll to the top of the inview element.
$('html > body').animate({'scrollTop' : this_pos}, 200).delay(1000);


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I solved this by adding a delay to the function firing upon scroll end. A delay of 100ms was enough to prevent it from firing too soon and adjusting the page with a scroll when it wasn't needed. Which was causing an infinite loop and weirdness on the page.

Here's my final code:

```
$(window).bind('scrollstop', function(e){

  var inview = '#' + $('.section-header:in-viewport:first').parent().parent().attr('id');
  var this_pos = $(inview).offset().top;    

  //animate to the top of the .page, with a 200 delay
   $('html > body').animate({'scrollTop' : this_pos}, 200);


  //a delay of 100 here is enough to stop a scrollend loop starting causing weirdness.
        }).delay(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe?

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: inview.offset().top - $('body').offset().top + $('body').scrollTop()
});​
```

Comment: This isn't having any affect. There's no scrolling at all (on scroll end). (unless I'm putting it in the wrong place? I just replaced the whole 'animate' line...

Comment: Well, since i'm not sure what your whole code looks like, have a look at scrollTop documentation, maybe it will lead you in the right direction: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: can you explain the logic behind that? inview offset minus the body offset (presumably 0?), plus body scrolltop (0 also?). I should say, it's not the animation to the page im having trouble with. It's that it fires every time the scroll ends. And then it scrolls to position, which fires it again causing a trange loop...